# Upgrade Pear Installer on a MediaTemple (dv) Dedicated-Virtual 3.5 server

Tags: php, pear

All,

Sorry in advance - I'm pretty naive when it comes to these things.

Anyway, I'm trying to install the Pear Mail module.

So, from the command line, I try this:

```
pear install --alldeps Mail
```

Here's the error I receive:

```
WARNING: channel "pear.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "channel-update pear.php.net" to update
pear/Mail requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.5.6), installed version is 1.5.0
No valid packages found
install failed
```

So, to upgrade the installer, I tried this:

```
pear upgrade PEAR
```

Here's the message I receive:

```
WARNING: channel "pear.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "channel-update pear.php.net" to update
pear/Archive_Tar requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.5.4), installed version is 1.5.0
pear/PEAR dependency package "pear/Archive_Tar" installed version 1.3.2 is not the recommended version 1.3.7, but may be compatible, use --force to install
No valid packages found
upgrade failed
```

What should I try next to upgrade the installer to at least 1.5.6?

Many thanks in advance!

Cheers,
Matt Stuehler

Answer (score 1):

First:
pear upgrade --force pear

Then:
pear install --alldeps Mail

This just worked for me on MT (dv) 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies to (dv) as well, but on (gs) one has to set the command line to PHP 5 instead of the default of 4 for PEAR to work:

http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/%28gs%29:Set_specific_PHP_version_for_command_line

Note that this action is different from setting the PHP version of your domains inside the MT control panel.